# как удалить последний символ строки/укоротить строку

Tags: php

Есть слово Финик**и** надо что бы стало Финик

```
$a = "Финики";
function($a,1)
```

Comment: Нужно просто отрезать последнюю букву или перевести множественное число в единственное? Если первое - ну потрудитесь уже заглянуть в какой-нибудь "Учебник PHP для самых маленьких"...

Comment: нужно первое я знаю как одно слово сделать, но мне нужна функция потому что слов много и у меня стоит if($a[$i]==$search)<br>если вы не поняли то там array

Comment: `substr("Финики", 0, -1)`

Comment: @MasterAlex сделай это ответом, пожалуйста, тогда после редактирования вопроса можно будет похожие вопросы дубликатами делать

Comment: @strangeqargo  MasterAlex а это неправильно для кириллицы...

Comment: для кириллицы в utf8, следует уточнить. Все равно, надо ответить, а потом удалить как дубликат соседнего вопроса, либо ответить подробнее, чтобы больше такого здесь не было

Comment: @strangeqargo у `substr` нет параметра для уточнения кодировки)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я об этом: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если вам доступно расширение mb_string, можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$a = "Финики";
echo mb_substr($a, 0, -1);
```

Функция `mb_substr()` возвращает подстроку первого аргумента, в качестве второго аргумента передается позиция откуда начинается подстрока (в нашем случае начало), а в качестве второго - длина подстроки (текущая длина строки минус один символ).